# Background color is not working with for loop

Tags: javascript

So my main goal is to randomize background every 1 second after clicking button.
The problem is I'm getting random RGB every second as my console outputs it, but the background changes only after the last iteration.

```
function random_background(){
var i;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    let red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let randomcolor = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
    console.log(randomcolor);
    document.body.style.background = randomcolor;
    sleep(1000);
}
}
```

Comment: Javascript can't do a real `sleep`. You can fake it with async / await (promises) . But as is it looks like your sleep() is more than likely just causing a UI freeze then continuing on

Comment: As mentioned Javascript doesn't have a sleep method, you want to use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) instead.

Comment: Use js promise if you want to sleep the cose con some seconds

Comment: That's not the problem, I defined sleep function.

Comment: Do “await sleep(5000)”

Comment: @sijicc How did you code a synchronous sleep function in JS? I'd love to see this code.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have any sleep method. To call a function after x times repeatedly you can use `setInterval`

```js
function random_background() {
   let red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
   let green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
   let blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
   let randomcolor = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
   document.body.style.background = randomcolor;
}
setInterval(random_background, 1000);
```

Comment: Probably dont really want the loop in there though

Comment: Thank you, It worked. Although why didn't defining function sleep didn't work?
```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
var start = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
break;
}
}
}
```

Comment: That is just a loop, it doesn't allow for the ui update nor any other code to run while it is running. Javascript is single threaded which means when it is busy so is the ui

Comment: Didn't know that. I guess thats the problem of learning without preparation. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setinterval` instead of `sleep` to give the browser a chance to do other things.  Eg updating the display

Answer (score 0):

There is no `sleep` function in Javascript. You should use `setInterval` to run a function until the interval is clear and at an interval of 1 second.

Also, i don't see why you need a `for` loop here so i've removed it.

```js
let interval = setInterval(() => {
  let red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  let green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  let blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  let randomcolor = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
  document.body.style.background = randomcolor;
}, 1000);
```